# Create User in postgres with pgx (SQLSTATE 42601)

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, pgx

I am trying to create a user in postgres. currently trying to use https://github.com/jackc/pgx as the driver to connect to the db. I have the below

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    conn, err := pgx.Connect(ctx, "host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer conn.Close(ctx)

    // create user
    _, err = conn.Exec(ctx, "CREATE USER $1 WITH PASSWORD $2", "moulick", "testpass")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

But I get this `ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" (SQLSTATE 42601)`

I don't get what's the problem here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"I don't get what's the problem here ?"* -- The problem is that [positional parameters](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-PARAMETERS-POSITIONAL) can be used only for *values*, and not for *identifiers*.

> A positional parameter reference is used to indicate a **value** that is supplied externally to an SQL statement.

You cannot use positional parameters in `CREATE USER <user_name>` the same way you cannot use them in `SELECT t.<column_name> FROM <table_name> AS t`.

```golang
user_name := "moulick"
_, err = conn.Exec(ctx, "CREATE USER "+user_name+" WITH PASSWORD $1", "testpass")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

If the `user_name` is not hardcoded, but instead comes from an unknown user input, you need to validate it yourself to avoid the possibility of SQL injections. This is not a difficult task since the [lexical structure of identifiers](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) is limited to a small set of rules, which you can further reduce to an even smaller subset if you like (e.g. disallowing diacritical marks and non-Latin letters):

> SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also
> letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore
> (_). Subsequent characters in an identifier or key word can be
> letters, underscores, digits (0-9), or dollar signs ($). Note that
> dollar signs are not allowed in identifiers according to the letter of
> the SQL standard, so their use might render applications less
> portable. The SQL standard will not define a key word that contains
> digits or starts or ends with an underscore, so identifiers of this
> form are safe against possible conflict with future extensions of the
> standard.

Comment: Please use some function to concatenate strings. On this example, ok, but it can lead to sql injection

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj What is the point you are trying to make? The answer already explicitly addresses SQL injections and how to avoid them in this specific case, does it not? And OP seemingly already knows that it's important to use positional parameters, wherever possible, to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: I was thinking in something like this: https://github.com/feiin/sqlstring

Comment: Yeah, SQL injection was what I was afraid of. But seems that pgx/v4 has a Sanitize function that I can probably use to prevent against SQL injection.